# How use @WorkerThread annotation in android project?

Tags: android, android-support-library

Before I used some way for call code in non ui thread (AsyncTask, Loader etc) . But now I try to use @WorkerThread annotation for method, it called some network request

```
@WorkerThread
    public void downloadInFile(final String url, final String rootDirectory, final OnFinishLoadAudioInFile onFinishLoadAudioInFile,
                               final OnUpdateLoadAudio onUpdateLoadAudio) {
        final String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url,  null, null);
        downloadFile(url, rootDirectory + File.pathSeparator + fileName, onFinishLoadAudioInFile, onUpdateLoadAudio);
    }
```

, and have `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. How use `@WorkerThread` annotation correctly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

WorkerThread annotation is only to add a requirement of calling thread not for automatically using a specific thread. You still have to do the threading.

Comment: But after added the annotation I get same exception as though I not added it. Is it true? May be I shoud to get another exception if I used annotation correctly

Comment: If you run lint you will get a warning or an error http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/annotations.html

Comment: AndroidAnnotation library do the work automatically i guess